# maven bundling jar in war file even though scope is provided

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I have declared in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

However, my WAR file still contains the jar file. Is there a secret flag "yes-really-dont-include-this" I can use?

Thanks

Comment: make sure other dependencies do not use servlet-api with non-provided scope: `mvn dependency:tree`

Answer (score 2):

You might still have an indirect `compile` dependecy on `servlet-api`. There might be some other dependency in you pom that declares dependency on it.

Inspect the dependency tree using

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

Comment: I don't see it in any other dependency, but it's still there in the war.